# Cannot get user by Id from database and display it's fields although I see them in response

Tags: angular, http, observable

What do I have:
HttpService with Method GetUser(id: number)

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

AddUser(us: User) {
  return this.http.post<any>(this.url + this.userString, us);
}

GetUsers() {
  return this.http.get(this.url + this.userString);
}

GetUser(id: number) {
  return this.http.get(this.url + this.userString + '/' + id.toString());
}
```

The User in model (Entity Framework)looks like it:

```
public class User
    {
        public int UserId {get; set; }
        public string ADName {get; set; }
        public string Email {get; set;}
    }
```

I call the GetUser(id) from Pipe where in transform function:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SendRecvService } from './SendRecv.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'idToValue'
})
export class IdToValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

 valuesUsers: any;

 constructor(private srv: SendRecvService) {
 }

 getUserName(id: number) {
   this.srv.GetUser(id).subscribe(response => {
   this.valuesUsers = response;
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

  transform(Argument1: number): any {
       // change UserId to UserName
       console.log(Argument1);

       this.getUserName(Argument1);
       return this.valuesUsers.adName;
  }

}
```

I got an Error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'adName' of undefined

Although I see in Http Response:

```
{userId: 1, adName: "mama", email: "mama@father.com"}
```

What do I see that it is not defined?
I got also Class of User in Angular but I do not know how can I map it.

New information. If I run such code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SendRecvService } from './SendRecv.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'idToValue'
})
export class IdToValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

  valuesUsers: any;

 constructor(private srv: SendRecvService) {
 }

getUserName3(id: number) {
  this.srv.GetUser(id).subscribe((response) => {
    this.valuesUsers = response;
    console.log(this.valuesUsers);
  });
}

transform(Argument1: number): any {
  this.getUserName3(Argument1);

  return 'hello';
}

}
```

I see in browser that the values that are sent are correct ones.

But as I understand I need to make it asynchronous. 
Unluckily the codes you have sent are not working.

Can we make changes step by step and see where lies the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework class spells it `ADName`. Your typescript code spells it `AdName`.

If you change your typescript spelling of the variable to `ADName`, that should sort it.

Edit: Sorry, re read the error. Your transform function will be called before your async http function returns the result. This means the variable you're trying to access will be `undefined` until your call returns.

```js
 getUserName(id: number) {
   return this.srv.GetUser(id).pipe(map(response => {
   this.valuesUsers = response;
  }), catchError((error) => console.log(error));
}

  transform(Argument1: number): any {
       // change UserId to UserName
       console.log(Argument1);

       this.getUserName(Argument1).subscribe((response) => {
          return response.ADName;
       }
  }
```

See this code for info.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still problem with ADName. It is not resolved by Angular.

Comment: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'. Property 'ADName' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: I think that the problem is with the function GetUser(id). Can you guide me through this and this async ?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.

Comment: What line? anymore info?

Comment: still the same problem:ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'adName' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring because you are trying to access `valuesUsers` before your async call `this.srv.GetUser(id)` came back with the response and `this.valuesUsers = response;` line gets executed. To make your `idToValue` pipe work as expected, let's change the code like this [Notice I have removed NOT needed code]:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SendRecvService } from './SendRecv.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'idToValue'
})
export class IdToValuePipe implements PipeTransform {     

 constructor(private srv: SendRecvService) {
 }         

  transform(Argument1: number): any {
       // change UserId to UserName
       console.log(Argument1);

       // let's return an observable from the transform method
       // this observable value will be unwrapped using async pipe
       // in the template where you will use this pipe
       // like this - {{id | idToValue | async}} 

       return this.srv.GetUser(id)
                  .pipe(
                        // lets map the response of GetUser to adName
                        // which you want ultimately return from the transform
                         map(user => user.adName)
                       );
  }

}
```

In template, you should use `async` pipe after `idToValue` pipe like this:

```
 <div>
  {{userId | idToValue | async}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Unluckily I got the same problem: Property 'adName' does not exist on type 'Object'